# Calculating the total thermal energy contained within an object

Tags: hard-science, super-powers, temperature

A character in my world has a superpower that allows them to convert all (or at least 99.99...%) of the thermal energy contained by the particles within a volume into directed kinetic energy, causing everything within that volume to instantaneously gain a certain velocity while being reduced to a temperature of near absolute zero.

I have been using [this](https://calculator.academy/thermal-energy-calculator/) thermal energy calculator to determine how much thermal energy a given object would hold, which, using a kinetic energy calculator, then lets me determine the acquired velocity. Assuming a 1kg ball of steel at 20C, I input m=1 (mass of the ball), c=420 (specific heat of steel), and deltaT= 293.15 (temperature difference between 20C and absolute zero). Is that all that needs to be done to calculate the total thermal energy within that steel ball, or is there something I am missing?

Comment: Would anyone care to explain why this post is being downvoted?

Comment: Down votes without comment is not only unhelpful, but detrimental to the platform, and frankly lazy.

Comment: Probably because the Q is only weakly related to worldbuilding (could easily be phrased for Physics), then from there people hopped on the downvote train.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but this isn't a worldbuilding problem (meaning you're not asking for help creating or consistently using a rule of your world). This is little more than asking for help with physics homework. Granted, it is an appropriate use of the [tag:hard-science] tag, but I'm having trouble conceiving of an answer that you could apply generally, say... to an apple pie. My opinion about why this isn't a WB question could change if you explain why you need it. (There's a reason SciFi authors don't explain everything to gnat's ear worth of detail.)

Comment: This post is being downvoted because (1) it asks how to calculate a quantity without specifying the meaning of the quantity to be calculated and (2) the answer is irrelevant anyway, because conservation of momentum is very much more fundamental than the conservation of energy, and conservation of momentum says that a body cannot accelerate unless acted upon by an external force. So, sorry, but no, no imaginable superpower can make the center of mass of a body move without applying an external foce. Moreover, if (3) we are happy to have only *part* of the object move that's an ordinary rocket.

Comment: Thermodynamics has never been one of my strengths but I'm fairly confident the one-word hard-science answer to the question is "no". If you're willing to forgo the laws of thermodynamics, you'll probably get much more exciting answers.

Comment: Beginning to hate the definition of the hard-science tag in this stack. In every instance its used 99% of the energy is wasted telling the OP how whatever is in question is impossible. One can get that in the relevant science stack. How about directing some of that intelect to extracting something the OP might need to help him in his creation.  Also pointing out the irony that building worlds in itself impossible, yet here we are.

Comment: @AlexP that's my bad for not specifying Alex. When I wrote superpower, I meant 'a magic ability unique to a person or a group of people' rather than 'a powerful and influential nation'. Hope that clears up any confusion.

Comment: @Gillgamesh The question of whether or not the [tag:hard-science] tag should exist has been asked before on [meta]. The consensus is that occasionally there really are worldbuilding issues that require a [tag:hard-science] response (usually concerning celestial mechanics). I was delighted that MS had asked a question appropriate for the tag because it's uncommon. Most users, especially new users, think it refers to the "hard science" book genre - because most people don't read tag wikis. O'course most people don't read national laws, either... but they're still held accountable to them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because asked for hard-science then denied the hard science with the phrase "super power."

Comment: @BobaFit I believe you're judging the question based on its [backstory](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8008/40609). The question itself is only asking about how to calculate a number - and that's a perfectly reasonable [tag:hard-science] question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [theorem of equipartition of energy](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/eqpar.html#c1) states that molecules in thermal equilibrium have the same average energy. Using the theorem, you can derive a formula for the average kinetic energy of particles in an object:

$$KE=N\frac{3}{2}k_{B}T.$$

On average, each particle has energy $\frac{3}{2}k_{B}T$, where $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant, $1.38\cdot10^{-23}$ $\text{J⋅K}^{-1}$, and $T$ [K] is the average temperature. $N$ is the average number of particles. I say "average" because objects are made of many different kinds of particles with different masses. However, the theorem states that each one has the same energy on average. So, we can calculate $N$ by:

$$N=\frac{mN_{A}}{M_{bar}}$$

where $m$ [g] is the mass of the object, $N_A$ is Avogadro's number, $6.022\cdot10^{23}$$\text{mol}^{-1}$, and $M_{bar}$ [g/mol] is the average molar mass of particles comprising the object:

$$M_{bar} = M_0(P_0) + M_1(P_1) + ... + M_n(P_n)$$

Where $P_i$ is the mass fraction corresponding to each particular element. If the object is a person made mostly of elemental carbon, oxygen, and hydrogen, at 55%, 45%, and 5% by mass respectively, then:

$$M_{bar} = 12.011(0.55) + 15.999(0.45) + 1.008(0.05)$$

Average body temperature of a human is 310 K, and average mass is 70 kg. Plugging the numbers, I get $KE$ of about about 20 kJ. To get a velocity, simply rearrange the equation for kinetic energy:

$$v = \sqrt{2 \frac{KE}{m}}.$$

I get 23.6 m/s.

Comment: Cheers, excellent answer. It might even work for an apple pie.... ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the interesting and helpful equations and explanation. Using this formula for a 1kg ball of iron (molar mass of 55.85, temperature of 293.15K) gets me a kinetic energy of 43 kJ, assuming I did the math right (my equation: (6.022x10^23/85)(1.5(1.38x10^-23))293.15). That KE then gets me a velocity of 293 m/s. However, when using the method I described in my question (specific heat of 450, change in temperature of 279.15), I get a thermal energy of 125.6kJ, which translates to a velocity  of 500 m/s.  Both these numbers work great for story purposes, but I'm still interested..

Comment: ...in knowing why there's such a large discrepancy between the two methods. Is the method I describe in my question simply not accurate for finding the total thermal energy of a body? Any info you might have on that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MS I'm not very sure. The Theorem of Equipartition of Energy only deals with particles' translational degrees of freedom. It could be that the extra energy is locked up in rotational and vibrational degrees of freedom, which TEE doesn't address (the formula you found is used to calculate chemical heat energy; Thermal energy is usually associated with [kinetic temperature](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/kintem.html#c1)).

Comment: There is also energy associated with intermolecular attractive forces that aren't being accounted for. I don't see anything wrong with either approach (yours or mine), as much energy goes out as what goes in, but the discrepancy is pretty large...

Comment: Yeah, if I had to guess (which I am because this subject isn't my strongest), specific heat capacities are empirical figures found through experiments and automatically take into account the intermolecular bond potentials. Equipartition deals only with the kinetic motion of particles.

Comment: Excellent maths! The one thing I'd add is that the component motion of the particles would be in multiple directions, so this power would probably make the object explode into frozen bits.

Answer (score 0):

If you want "hard-science" then you need to know that it is physically impossible to do what you suggest. The second law of thermodynamics absolutely does not allow it.

The maximum efficiency that heat can be converted to work depends on having a cold reservoir into which to dump the heat. This efficiency is given by the following formula.

Efficiency = $1 - T_c/T_h$

That is, it is 1 minus the ratio of the cold to the hot temperatures. These are expressed in degrees above absolute zero.

Room temperature is round-about 300 K. (That's a quite warm room at 27C.) If you had some object that was, for example, boiling water, that's 373K. You get an efficiency of 1 - 300/373, or about 19%. That 19% applies only while the hot thing is at boiling temperature. As it cools towards room temperature, the efficiency gets worse and worse. So at 50C it is only 7% or so.

If you had some nearby handy extremely cold reservoir, you could possibly dump heat into that.  So, for example, if your superguy had a huge dewar of liquid nitrogen. That's about 77 K.  Then at the start you could get up to abut 74% efficiency. As the temperature of the target fell, the efficiency of the process falls. Half way to liquid nitrogen temps it is below 40%.

These calculations assume perfect efficiency of whatever engine you might select. They will, of course, lose some of the theoretical efficiency to friction, etc.

So the result is, even if you were prepared to walk around with a huge cryogenic flask full of liquid nitrogen, you can't get more than a small fraction of the heat energy out as work.

Comment: Readers please note this answer is a Frame Challenge.

Comment: The question asks about "thermal energy", not heat. True, the question does not specify what is the meaning of the ambiguous phrase "thermal energy", but the answer should begin by explaining that it assumes that by thermal energy the question means heat content or enthalpy or whatever.

Comment: For a steal ball that stays at 1 atmosphere, the enthalpy, thermal energy, and heat content are indistinguishable.

Comment: Thank you, but please note that this is a super power and as such the laws of physics (and therefore the carnot efficiency) do not necessarily apply. The hard-science tag is only in relation to the stated question, which asks after a method for determining the thermal energy contained within an object.